# Raster Dataset projection problem

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, arccatalog, raster-dataset

I have a problem connected with my Raster Dataset projection. Two of its bands cannot be shown in some scale - only under 1:1500, when I use 'Zoom to raster resolution' option.
Histograms for all 3 bands are correct, I even calculated statistics and did pyramids.

Below you can find screens of it (3rd band is presented same as band 2):

[image]

I store the Raster Dataset in a file geodatabase (.gdb).

Answer (score 2):

Try converting to another raster format. When I have had this issue in the past I have found that converting to GRID resolves the issue. 
The [Raster to other format (conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000032000000) function should help.